# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value in table when trying to create an new connection

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to a local RabbitMQ server from Java. I've currently got my `ConnectionFactory` instance configured within Spring like so:

```
<bean class="org.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="5672"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

When I try to obtain a new connection:

```
connectionFactory.newConnection();
```

I get the following error thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value in table
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.fieldValueSize(Frame.java:306)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.tableSize(Frame.java:246)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ValueWriter.writeTable(ValueWriter.java:120)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.MethodArgumentWriter.writeTable(MethodArgumentWriter.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Connection$StartOk.writeArgumentsTo(AMQImpl.java:161)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Method.toFrame(Method.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:316)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:298)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingRpc(AMQChannel.java:233)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:224)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:209)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:202)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:340)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
    at com.tkassembled.dispatcher.service.RabbitMQQueueService.init(RabbitMQQueueService.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

In the RabbitMQ logs:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 13-Jul-2012::15:24:30 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.1159.0> from 127.0.0.1:55154
{handshake_timeout,frame_header}
```

---

#### Update

I'm also now noticing something really strange. If I create the `ConnectionFactory` instance in Spring, then all calls to `newConnection()` will fail terribly, even if I'm not setting any properties on it:

```
<bean class="org.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <!-- nothing -->
</bean>
```

However, if I create the `ConnectionFactory` instance outside of the Spring container and then call `newConnection()`, no errors are thrown:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");

Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems kind of weird to get such a random error that only occurs when the `ConnectionFactory` was created in the Spring container. What about the Spring container would be so dramatically different than creating it in raw Java?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it was in my header:

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("user-id", event.uid);
[...]
channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, "???", new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().headers(headers).build(), payload.getBytes(UTF_8));
```

(the BasicProperties.Builder() has been shorten for visibility)

The problem was solved with a String value in the header instead of the UUID:

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("user-id", event.uid.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some wrapper of Rabbitmq ConnectionFactory. It's configured from within Spring configuration with host/port/etc. And has method getConnection() that simply do

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(); 
factory.setHost(getHostName());
factory.setUsername(getUserName());
factory.setPassword(getPassword());
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

If you need only one connection (really?), you can use this method in the constructor...